# Angular js testing controllers functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have controller that look like this:

```
function myController() {

   this.init();

   this.getSomething();

}
```

Let's say i want to test only the getSomething function, the problem is that the init function also run and if for example there is a get request in this function, the test force me to expect this. There is a way to solve this problem or this is how it works?

Comment: you can make use of 'spies' - http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html